# How many ways to combine $7$ women and $6$ men in a committee of $6$ given each sex must be represented.

Tags: combinatorics, statistics

I thought something along the lines of: Number of ways to pick out $1$ woman from seven times the number of ways to pick out $1$ man of $6$ times the numbers of ways to arrange the rest $11$ and $4$.  $7\choose 1$ $6\choose1$ $11\choose4$ $= 13860$.

But this is not correct...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If only man are in commite we can do ${7\choose 6}$ commites and only one commite with only womans. So commites where only one gender is represented is $${7\choose 6}+1 =7+1=8$$

So we have $$ {13\choose 6}-8=...$$ commites.

Comment: That is correct, thank you. Could you elaborate on the first part, "if only one sex is represented".  I don't think I understood that entirely. Sorry i'm new to combinatorics and I find it quite confusing

Edit: Nvm I understood it now! thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Let M be the men,
and W be the women.
 number of ways to get a committee of 6, so that each gender is represented is
5W + M,

4W + 2M,

3W +3M,

2W + 4M,

W + 5M,

which is = 7C1 * 6C5 + 6C2*5C4 +5C3*4C3+4C4 *3C2 + 2C1

= 7*6 + 15*5 + 10*4 + 1*3 + 2

## = 42 + 75 + 40 + 3 + 2

162 ways

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).